# Getting Java exception running the code on other machines

Tags: java, string, exception, double, numberformatexception

I made a project in Java, if I run the project from my machine everything works fine, but if I share the jar file and execute from another machine it does not work. I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10,00"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:651)
    at model.components.Transaction.<init>(Transaction.java:33)
    at model.events.components.AddTransactionListener.actionPerformed(AddTransactionListener.java:87)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I suspect this is the code that is producing the error:

```
 double transactionAmount = 0;
        try {
            if (addTransactionPanel.getAmountField().getText().equals("") || Double.parseDouble(addTransactionPanel.getAmountField().getText()) < 0.0)
                throw new MyException("Enter a valid amount!");
            transactionAmount = Double.parseDouble(addTransactionPanel.getAmountField().getText());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            errorMessage += e.getMessage() + "\n";
            errorCount++;
        }
```

`addTransactionPanel.getAmountField().getText` returns the text of a JTextField.

As I said before  if I run the project on my machine I don't get the error (Im on Pop-os).
I made a virtual machine with Windows 10 and it works fine. I tried the code on Ubuntu which is on another disk partition and it also works.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Possibly a localisation issue, but `10,00` is not a valid decimal value.  In these cases I'd consider using a `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is, with locale german for instance

Comment: I typed 10 and it parsed the value to 10,00 double. If I run the code on my laptop it works fine.

Comment: @Raff32 Then, that's you problem, different locale's have different formatting requirements.  Use a `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` instead ... or `NumberFormat` instead

Comment: @Jens Yes, but the exception is clearly stating that it's not, within in it's context  - aren't different languages fun.

Comment: Just to be clear, within the context of the exception "`10,00` is not a valid decimal value".  From this you need to work backwards and determine why.  The most "likely" cause is a localisation issue, which is why, things like `JFormattedTextField`, `JSpinner` and even `NumberFormat` are generally better choices

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried replacing the JTextField: `NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        this.amountField = new JFormattedTextField(format);` but I still get the error.

Comment: Add `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());` add see what it prints on your two platforms. Also, make sure you're using `JFormattedTextField#getValue` and not `getText` and still continuing to use `Double.parse`

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, I'm guessing that this is a localisation issue.

You could start by adding `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());` to your code to see what locale each platform is using.

Generally, you should be making use of `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` to deal with the input format and then use their `getValue` method, which will actually perform the parsing, for example...

```
// By default, my locale is en_AU, so this is just for demonstration
// purposes, don't do this to your users
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(format);
textField.setColumns(10);
add(textField);
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Will need to cast the result, as it
        // returns Object by default
        System.out.println(textField.getValue());
    }
});
```

If I enter `10.10` into the field, it will output `1010`, if I input `10,10` it will output `10.10`

If I use `Locale.getDefault()` instead (ie `en_AU` in my case), if I enter `10.10`, it will output `10.10`, if I input `10,10`, it will output `1010`